# Get ArraySegment<byte> from System.ServiceModel.Channels Message

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, soap

I had to modify SOAP headers so I override

```
public override ArraySegment<byte> WriteMessage(Message message, int maxMessageSize, BufferManager bufferManager, int messageOffset)
```

but I have to return ArraySegment, so how can I get ArraySegment from System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message

Comment: Please check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.channels.messageencoder?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1#examples)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public override ArraySegment<byte> WriteMessage(Message message, int maxMessageSize, BufferManager bufferManager, int messageOffset)
{
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
    XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(stream, this.writerSettings);
    message.WriteMessage(writer);
    writer.Close();

    byte[] messageBytes = stream.GetBuffer();
    int messageLength = (int)stream.Position;
    stream.Close();

    int totalLength = messageLength + messageOffset;
    byte[] totalBytes = bufferManager.TakeBuffer(totalLength);
    Array.Copy(messageBytes, 0, totalBytes, messageOffset, messageLength);

    ArraySegment<byte> byteArray = new ArraySegment<byte>(totalBytes, messageOffset, messageLength);
    return byteArray;
}
```

Copied from the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.channels.messageencoder?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1#examples).